# Implementing linear regression using keras resulting nan loss

Tags: keras, linear-regression

I am a newbie of keras. When I am implementing linear regression,I encounter a nan loss, which obsess me a lot. I put my source code below:

```
from keras.layers import Dense,Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1,input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='sgd',metrics=['mse'])
x = np.linspace(1,100,1e3)
y = 3*x + 1 + np.random.normal(size=x.shape)
model.fit(x,y,batch_size=100)
```

Then the output of loss is nan.
  But when I change the training data, corresponding code is:

```
x = np.linspace(1,10,1e3)
```

everything is fine, which finally I can get the w approximating 3.0 and the b approximating 1.
  Anybody knows why this would happen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `x = np.linspace(1,100,1e3)` will give you 1000 numbers with values from 1 up to 100. Imagine all those numbers multiplied by some random value `w` to create your prediction (`x * w`), then squared and summed to get the loss value with the MSE function. The number is so big that is overflowing, going from `inf` to `nan`.

A good practice is to keep your data with mean 0.0 and low variance (e.g. 1)

In this case an easy fix will be to divide your data by 100 like this:

```
x = np.linspace(1,100,1e3) / 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a NN rookie and I have spent two whole days to make a linear regression model work with Keras until I finally found out the data needed to be normalised for a  quicker learning.

You can add these two lines to your program :

```
from·keras.layers·import·BatchNormalization
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```